# Set the plot y-axis and x-axis ratio equal

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure(1)
plt.subplot(211)
xs = np.linspace(-5,5,500)
ys = np.sqrt(5**2 - xs**2)

plt.plot(xs,ys)
plt.plot(xs,-ys)

plt.subplot(212)
plt.plot(xs, xs**2)
plt.show()
```

here is the code i generate, was wondering that if i want keep the upper plot x and y ratio be 1:1 so that the ball will always look round no matter how many subplot inside this figure.

I tried to find it from the website, seems not a simple solution..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create your subplot, you can tell it:

```
plt.subplot(211, aspect='equal')
```

If you've already created the subplot, you have to grab the current axes, which you can do using `plt.gca`, then call the `set_aspect` method:

```
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal')
```

Or, you can keep track of the axes from the beginning:

```
ax = plt.subplot(211)
ax.set_aspect('equal')
```

You may have to call

```
plt.draw()
```

In order to update the plot.